# Live Audio Stream

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to setup live internet radio station using icecast server and want my stream to work in all modern browsers. My client only produces .ogg stream. All browsers doesn't play .ogg stream. For eg the .ogg stream I have setup works in chrome but doesn't work in IE. How should I make it run in all browsers?

1. Is there a way I can convert .ogg stream to .mp3 or any other format on the fly
2. Embed a audio player in the browser which can play .ogg stream.

Or Any other advice would be helpful.

Regards,
Hitesh Bhutani

Comment: Maybe something like this would be of use: https://gist.github.com/TooTallNate/4170656

Comment: What Icecast source client do you use for streaming?

Comment: @AlexeyVParamonov I am using a Dj Software virtual dj.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Change encoding format from OGG to MP3 in your Virtual DJ software. Keep in mind that Firefox will not be able to play mp3 streams on some platforms using HTML5 audio tag due to licensing limitations.
2. Install some kind of transcoding software on your server (where you have Icecast installed and running), for example liquidosap (https://www.liquidsoap.info/). Liquidsoap can (among other things) take your stream as an input and transcode it to sereveral formats, for example - mp3, aac, ogg and then your Icecast server will have several mount points available, for example http://yourserver.com:8000/stream.mp3, http://yourserver.com:8000/stream.ogg, http://yourserver.com:8000/stream.aac and then you can create a small javascript that wil detect browser version and choose suitable stream.
3. Use HTML5 media player like jPlayer (http://jplayer.org/) or Soundmanager2 (http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). These players can automatically detect browser version and select suitable stream type, also if they can't play the stream using HTML5 `<audio>` tag, they will fall back to internal Flash based player.

The most advanced way is to combine (2) and (3) methods, that will give you the most browser support.

[Supported audio coding formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats)

Comment: Thanks for the details. I will try on these options and if it works i will mark the answer as correct. Also, I have tried jPlayer and it is not able to play .ogg file in IE 11

Comment: Then change the stream to mp3 in your Virtual DJ and try jPlayer one more time, it will play mp3 stream in IE and use fallback Flash player to play mp3 format in Firefox, I am sure that will work because I have tried that myself. Unfortunately, I have not tried OGG + IE + jPlayer combination - I usually work with MP3 streams, they have better support anyway.

Comment: @HiteshBhutani how is it going? Free to ask, I will be glad to help

Comment: I am still evaluating options. Didn't get time to look it. But Option 1 is definitely out of picture. My client will always produce .ogg stream and i would have to find out a way to use it in all browsers because .mp3 formats has some licensing and trademark concerns with it. I am trying to find out if I can use a player like jPlayer to play an .ogg stream in IE and other browsers with flash as a fall back option. But i think IE doesn't support .ogg at all.

Comment: Firefox plays MP3 just fine on platforms that provide the codec.

Comment: @HiteshBhutani Why not Opus?

Comment: @Brad My client always produce a .ogg stream. Is it possible for me to change the stream to Opus format on the fly? Also, the stream url i create is dynamic and different for different clients

Comment: @HiteshBhutani Sure, you can transcode, but it hurts sound quality and doesn't fix your problem.  If you're concerned about licensing, then you have the same problems in the end anyway.  And, why are you stuck to Ogg?  Opus is royalty-free.

Comment: @Brad My Client can only produce .ogg stream. Is it possible for me to use just that stream and play it in all browsers? I thinking of using jwPlayer. I think it has cross-browser compatibility

Comment: @HiteshBhutani No, it isn't.  You must use codecs that browsers support.  Your reason for only using Ogg makes no sense at all.  Is this a legal issue or a technical one?

Comment: @Brad Its a technical issue. Let me give you a little more clear picture. I think you are the man who can solve my problem. I have a web app which generates a unique url for an audio-stream for every user like this: http:// ip-of-icecast-server/webapp-name/1234.ogg where 1234.ogg is the unique stream id my webapp generates every time a live stream is setup. User copies this unique stream url and uses this in his client and connect to icecast server and starts live streaming. The client only produces .ogg stream. "COMPLETING THE QUESTION IN NEXT COMMENT"

Comment: @Brad cont....   Now anyone with this unique URL can listen to live stream. Since the client only produces .ogg stream it only works in Chrome,FF and not in IE and Safari. How do i make it cross-browser compatible?

Comment: @HiteshBhutani You either transcode it, sending other streams to Icecast, which is totally possible but you still have to have a license for the codec you're using, and is a total waste of CPU, and reduces audio quality.  Or, you can start with the streams in compatible codecs from the beginning, which is strongly recommended.  There are no reasonable ways to play back Ogg Vorbis in browsers that don't support it.  There are JavaScript codecs, but they aren't fast or efficient, and don't work all that well yet.

Comment: The link to Liquidsoap in the answer doesn't work anymore, the new URL is https://www.liquidsoap.info/