# Convert Icecast .ogg stream to mp3

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, icecast

I haven been trying to figure this out for more than a week now but still not successful. I am able to do a live audio stream in .ogg format using virtual DJ as the client and Icecast as streaming server. .ogg stream plays successfully in Firefox and Chrome but doesn't play in IE. How can i play the same stream in both the formats .ogg and .mp3 so that it is supported in all modern browsers although i can only produce one kind of stream i.e .ogg using my client virtual DJ.

I want my users to listen to my same stream irrespective of the browsers they use.

Please help. I really need to get this going.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live Audio Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783277/live-audio-stream)

Comment: Your question was already answered when you posted it 5 days ago.

Comment: @Brad I am not sure why the answer was deleted... Ken gave a very elaborative diagram for the solution. It wasn't that clear from the earlier solution. Can I have Ken's answer back on the forum I need to re-read it.

Comment: @HitechBhutani That's up to K3N, since he was the one that deleted his answer.

Comment: I deleted it since there was a dup that seem to be a better response, undeleted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualDJ can only broadcast in one format at the time, either as Ogg or MP3.

To get both formats you would have to go through a middle server which trans-code one format into the other and broadcast on a different port:

[image: diagram]

You may be able to use something like [VideoLAN (VLC)](https://wiki.videolan.org/Streaming/#Transcoding_commandline_string_structure) to do this which can output as Icecast:

```
vlc.exe --sout "#transcode{[TRANSCODE_OPTIONS]}:std{[OUTPUT_OPTIONS]}" INPUT
```

For example converting input to a mp3 stream (ibid.):

```
vlc --sout "#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=OUTPUT}" INPUT
```

You can also set up trans-coding via the GUI. See more details in the provided link.

When the two streams are setup you can define them as audio sources:

```
<audio>
  <source src="//host:8000/mount1" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="//host:8001/mount2" type="audio/mpeg" />
<audio>
```

Comment: It's "Ogg" as it's not an acronym and it's "Icecast" as we don't camel-case.

Comment: @TBR "
   
 
It's "Ogg" as it's not an acronym and it's "Icecast" as we don't camel-case." Maybe I did that on purpose.. ;) lol, anyways, corrected. nice job on the server btw.